# CultureInfo.GetCultures (CultureTypes.NeutralCultures) DisplayName property gives different results when the application is published

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

**Live:**

[image: publish-state]

**Local:**

[image: local-state]

**Code:**

```
<select name="Language" asp-for="Language" class="form-control" id="Language">
    @foreach (var cultureInfo in Model.CultureInfos)
    {
        if (cultureInfo.TwoLetterISOLanguageName == "en")
        {
            <option selected value="@cultureInfo.Name">@cultureInfo.DisplayName</option>
        }
        else
        {
            <option value="@cultureInfo.Name">@cultureInfo.DisplayName</option>
        }
    }
</select>
```

This is probably because of the machine on which we publish the application. But I don't know how we can solve this problem. For example, is it enough to change the language of the machine?

Comment: Try to clear the browser data (cache, cookie and so on) and recheck whether it works. Besides, you could try to use the NativeName or EnglishName, instead of the DisplayName.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. The first method didn't work but I'll try NativeName or EnglishName.

Comment: Using EnglishName the problem was solved. Thank you @Zhi Lv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, to fix it, we can use the **EnglishName**, instead of the DisplayName.